# vuelidate: validate items list that depend on its values

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I need to validate the elements of a list in relation to a value of the element itself.

Is it possible or should I create a validation for each product?

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: '',
    sons: [
      {amount: 20, pending: 50}, 
      {amount: 30, pending: 150}
    ]
  },
  validations: {
    text: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(5)
    },
    sons: {
      minLength: 3,
      $each: {
        amount: {
          maxValue: maxValue(this.sons[x].pending) // how to set x?
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e0tL4yph/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In the Vuelta repository, I published this question and the answer is:

> In that case you want to use the second argument of validation function.

```
amount: {
  ltePending: (amount, { pending }) => amount <= pending
}
```

It works as I wanted!